# Как посмотреть на какой стадии загрузка страницы сайта?

Tags: веб-программирование, отладка

Не уверен, что точно сформулировал.
Делаю сайт. Заметил ,что страницы при открытии стали грузиться заметно дольше. Как можно посмотреть, что конкретно сейчас происходит? Что скачивается, обрабатывается и т.д...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В современных браузерах есть "инструменты разработчика". В Opera, к примеру, есть замечательный Opera Dragonfly, для его вызова надо в контекстном меню в любом месте страницы выбрать "Проинспектировать элемент". В Dragonfly для вашей задачи есть вкладка "Сеть", подвкладка "Журнал сети". Там показано графически, сколько что грузилось.

Comment: Спасибо! Я там раньше только верстку смотрел, теперь буду знать.

Comment: Для вёрстки, он, кстати, тоже очень удобен)

Answer (score 2):

opera - dragonfly, firefox - firebug, chrome, ie 9+ встроенные инструменты разработчика(F12), safari тоже встроенный, везде вкладка "сеть"

Answer (score 1):

[**Firebug**](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/firebug/) для FireFox.

[image]